# Is it possible to setup multiple VirtualService that share same host in a single Gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Let say I have VirtualService `Foo` that has rule to manage `team.company.com/foo` http path, and bind it to the Gateway `TeamGateway` (that has host team.company.com).
Then introduce another VirtualService `Bar` to manage `team.company.com/bar` rule path to certain backend, bind to the same Gateway `TeamGateway`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you can do this by matching the uri prefix and even using 1 VirtualService.

[Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Gateway) should look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: your-new-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: your-new-gateway-controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - team.company.com
```

After defining Gateway you create [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService) matching it to different prefixes:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs-rule
spec:
  hosts:
  - team.company.com
  gateways:
  - your-new-gateway
  http:
  - match:
      uri:
        prefix: /foo/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: your_1.svc.cluster.local #Kubernetes underlying service name
  - match:
      uri:
        prefix: /bar/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: your_2.svc.cluster.local #Kubernetes underlying service name
```

Comment: yup i know about using 1 virtualService. The thing is the backend (foo and bar) is managed by different/independent CICD automation (through different helm release). so using 1 virtualservice is not ideal.

Comment: the same way you create 2 Virtualservices that are mapped to `gateways:- your-new-gateway`. 1 VirtualService - 1 prefix match

Comment: yes, i realized that since istio-1.0.1 it now supports merging multiple virtualservice that binds to the same gateway (assuming there is no conflicted rule). So i have to upgrade my istio version first. thanks VKR